# Is it possible to replace background image with text?

Tags: html, css

I know it's possible to replace text with a background image but was wondering if it's possible to do it the otherway. I have a some an html element (a href tag) with background-image css property set to an image and I want to replace this with some text but doesn't seem to work.
I know I can remove the image to none using the css background-image property but can't seem to update it to text.
Currently the background-image is applied to it using a CSS

Comment: No, you can't have text in place of a `background-image` (unless the image contains text, of course, but that wouldn't be *instead of*). What is it you're trying to do? What problem are you trying to solve? You may be able to use [pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content), but we can't offer specific advice without some information, really.

Comment: I'm using the kendo editor control which has some default tool buttons with images but I would like to replace the default image with text in the page using the editor control, I know I can just create a specific image and use that instead but would be nice to use some text instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the text you want in the HTML between the anchor tag

```
<a href"#">TEXT HERE</a>
```

Note:  Generally, unless a very good specific reason is given to why your image has the text on it, you should be putting the text in the code.  So what you are doing is converting to a better practice than before, which is good.

Comment: No, already tried this and tried setting the background-image none also.

Comment: Can't really do much without seeing your code and what specifically it is that you're changing in the first place.  Your question above was very vague, if it is what I am interpretting it as, then the above should have worked, if it does not work as you say then there is something wrong in the process or in how you are implementing the changes.  Edit your original post with some actual code or a link to what it is you want to actually replace the image on, then I can help further.